Map a table, replacing values based on other cell
I would like to map a table replacing some data based on data from another cell..
In my below example I would like to remove data from the "Status" column if the cell to the left on the "price" column is empty.
I know it is possible to do it very simply duplicating the table and having a simple =IF formula manually placed where needed, here I try to see how I can achieve this in only one single formula; I managed to do it but my solution is quite complex
Start table



Price
Status
Price
Status
Price
Status




12
Paid
23
Forecasted

Forecasted



Paid
22
Forecasted
7
Forecasted


30
Paid
10
Forecasted
15
Forecasted


5
Paid
7
Forecasted
30
Forecasted


10
Paid
40
Forecasted
6
Forecasted


10
Paid
5
Forecasted
8
Forecasted


2
Paid

Forecasted
9
Forecasted


4
Paid

Forecasted

Forecasted



Desired output
As you can see I want to remove the "Paid" "Forecasted" values when its corresponding left cell is empty too



Price
Status
Price
Status
Price
Status




12
Paid
23
Forecasted






22
Forecasted
7
Forecasted


30
Paid
10
Forecasted
15
Forecasted


5
Paid
7
Forecasted
30
Forecasted


10
Paid
40
Forecasted
6
Forecasted


10
Paid
5
Forecasted
8
Forecasted


2
Paid


9
Forecasted


4
Paid







I managed to do it with the following function:
=WRAPROWS(TOCOL(BYROW(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A2:F9;0;0);2);LAMBDA(x;if(left(join("/";x);1)="/";"";x)));0;0);6) but as stated above.. this may be over complex, there is surely a more simple way. I wanted to use a =MAP formula but could not figure out how to manage the empty or not condition from left cell and apply it to the right cell
Thanks very much

May I ask if the actual table has 6 columns and not 2? Also, do you not want the blank cells removed?

Yes the table structure got 6 cols and I do need to keep the blank cells

An IF formula can be used surgically with OFFSET to manipulate the data as needed:
=ARRAYFORMULA(HSTACK(A1:A9,IF(A1:E9<>"",B1:F9,)))

If A1:F9 is the data set, we get A1:E9 with  the last column  removed. If that is not empty, We use B1:F9 as the result, with the first column removed from the range. By using IF this way, we have the desired result except the first column, which we Horizontally STACK it as is later.



Price
Status
Price
Status
Price
Status




$12.00
Paid
23
Forecasted






22
Forecasted
7
Forecasted


$30.00
Paid
10
Forecasted
15
Forecasted


$5.00
Paid
7
Forecasted
30
Forecasted


$10.00
Paid
40
Forecasted
6
Forecasted


$10.00
Paid
5
Forecasted
8
Forecasted


$2.00
Paid


9
Forecasted


$4.00
Paid








Hello, I would have not think of that, thanks! I still wonder if there would be a way of doing it using MAP formula

@AlexM   Not as elegant as my IF, but as a theoretical exercise: =LET(d,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A2:F9),2),m, MAP(INDEX(d,,1),INDEX(d,,2),LAMBDA(a,l, IF(a="",{"",""},{a,l}))), WRAPROWS(TOCOL(m),6))

Thanks very much that is what I looked for in terms of logic!!
PS: I add to make a quick fix to the IF   replacing ";" by ""  IF(a="";{""\""};{a\l}) so it worked, it may be related to my sheet settings.
=LET(d,WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:F8),2),m, MAP(INDEX(d,,1),INDEX(d,,2),LAMBDA(a,l, IF(a="",{""\""},{a\l}))), WRAPROWS(TOCOL(m),6))

Use QUERY
First of all, if I understood you correctly, you just want to use formulas which are relatively simple or readable. With this, I suggest you try and use the QUERY function. However, it does remove all empty cells (based on the price column) due to the query SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL.
Solutions
1. WRAPROWS + LET + QUERY
(NOTE: this solution does not include the headers while the data are arranged differently since the data pairs were shifted to fill in the empty cells)
Formula:
=LET(a; WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A2:F9);2);
     b; QUERY(a;"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL");
     IFNA(WRAPROWS(TOCOL(b);6)))

Output:













12
Paid
23
Forecasted
22
Forecasted


7
Forecasted
30
Paid
10
Forecasted


15
Forecasted
5
Paid
7
Forecasted


30
Forecasted
10
Paid
40
Forecasted


6
Forecasted
10
Paid
5
Forecasted


8
Forecasted
2
Paid
9
Forecasted


4
Paid







2. LET + QUERY
Formula:
=LET(a; QUERY(A1:B9;"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL");
     b; QUERY(C1:D9;"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL");
     c; QUERY(E1:F9;"SELECT * WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL");
     IFNA(HSTACK(a;b;c)))

Output:



Price
Status
Price
Status
Price
Status




12
Paid
23
Forecasted
7
Forecasted


30
Paid
22
Forecasted
15
Forecasted


5
Paid
10
Forecasted
30
Forecasted


10
Paid
7
Forecasted
6
Forecasted


10
Paid
40
Forecasted
8
Forecasted


2
Paid
5
Forecasted
9
Forecasted


4
Paid







References

QUERY
LET


Feel free to ask anything about the answer posted above.

Thanks very much for your input, as I do need to keep the blank cells I will be a bit limited
